# R: convert email addresses into unique integers

Tags: r, char, int, converters

R beginner with what seems to be a pretty simple problem :
I have a number of email logs that I have read into R in the format:

```
>log1
    Date        Time            From                 To
1   2000-01-01  00:00:00    bob@mail.com            test1@mail.com
2   2000-01-02  01:00:00    carolyn @mail.com       test2@mail.com
3   2000-01-03  02:00:00    chris@mail.com          test3@mail.com
4   2000-01-04  03:00:00    chris @mail.com         test4@mail.com
5   2000-01-05  04:00:00    alan@mail.com           test5@mail.com
6   2000-01-06  05:00:00    alan.@mail.com          test6@mail.com
```

I need to change log1$From and log1$To to a global unique numeric identifier, such that when I read in other logs later any given email address will receive the same identifier as previous logs.

I have tried:

```
id <- as.numeric(as.character(log1[,3])))
id<-as.numeric(levels(log1[,3])))
id <- charToRaw(log1[,4]), base=16)
```

Would some kind soul please help me out – Thanks!

Apologies should probably have included this:

```
 Date=c( "01/01/2000" ,"02/01/2000" ,"03/01/2000", "04/01/2000" ,"05/01/2000" ,"06/01/2000","07/01/2000","08/01/2000",
    "09/01/2000","10/01/2000","11/01/2000", "12/01/2000" ,"13/01/2000", "14/01/2000", "15/01/2000","16/01/2000"
    ,"17/01/2000","18/01/2000","19/01/2000","20/01/2000","01/01/2000","02/01/2000")
    Time=c("00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00", "03:00:00" ,"04:00:00" ,"05:00:00", "06:00:00" ,"07:00:00", "08:00:00", "09:00:00" ,"10:00:00",
    "11:00:00", "12:00:00","13:00:00", "14:00:00","15:00:00","16:00:00","17:00:00","18:00:00","19:00:00","00:00:00" ,"00:00:00")
    From=c("bob.shults@mail.com","carolyn.green@mail.com","chris.long@mail.com","christi.nicolay@mail.com","alan.aronowitz@mail.com","alan.comnes@mail.com",
    "dab@sprintmail.com","ana.correa@mail.com","andrew.fastow@mail.com","elena.kapralova@mail.com","bob.shults@mail.com","carolyn.green@mail.com",
    "chris.long@mail.com","christi.nicolay@mail.com","alan.aronowitz@mail.com","alan.comnes@mail.com","dab@sprintmail.com","ana.correa@mail.com",
    "andrew.fastow@mail.com","elena.kapralova@mail.com","bob.shults@mail.com","bob.shults@mail.com")
    To=c("ana.correa@mail.com","test2@mail.com","test3@mail.com","test4@mail.com","test5@mail.com","test6@mail.com","test7@mail.com",
    "test8@mail.com","test9@mail.com","test10@mail.com","test11@mail.com","test12@mail.com","test13@mail.com","test14@mail.com",
    "test15@mail.com","test16@mail.com","test17@mail.com","test18@mail.com","test19@mail.com","test20@mail.com","ana.correa@mail.com","ana.correa@mail.com")
    log<-data.frame(Date=Date,Time=Time,From=From,To=To)
```

Attempt at using MD5 to generate globally unique identifiers: Note how the identifier for ana.correa@mail.com is a correct match within ID_to but is not within ID_from

```
ID_to<-data.frame()
    ID_from<-data.frame()

    for (i in 1:nrow(log)){
    to<-as.numeric(paste('0x', substr(rep(hmac('secret',log[i,4], algo='md5'), 2), c(1, 9, 17, 25), c(8, 16, 24, 32)),sep=""))
    (ID_to<-rbind(ID_to,to))

    from<-as.numeric(paste('0x', substr(rep(hmac('secret',log[i,3], algo='md5'), 2), c(1, 9, 17, 25),c(8, 16, 24, 32)),sep=""))
    (ID_from<-rbind(ID_from,from))

    }

    ID_to[,3]<-paste(ID_to[,1],ID_to[,2], sep="")
    ID_from[,3]<-paste(ID_from[,1],ID_from[,2], sep="")

    edgelist<-data.frame(ID_from[,3],log[,3],ID_to[,3],log[,4],log[,1],log[,2])
    print(edgelist)
    ID_from...3.                 log...3.           ID_to...3.            log...4.   log...1. log...2.
    27488842661591306920      bob.shults@mail.com 18727221862165338513 ana.correa@mail.com 01/01/2000 00:00:00
    38124472891255273775   carolyn.green@mail.com  1251903296725454474      test2@mail.com 02/01/2000 01:00:00
    29070047663451376630      chris.long@mail.com 17074276751156451031      test3@mail.com 03/01/2000 02:00:00
    8261398433828474582 christi.nicolay@mail.com  1563683670909194033      test4@mail.com 04/01/2000 03:00:00
    18727221862165338513  alan.aronowitz@mail.com 26735368323826533112      test5@mail.com 05/01/2000 04:00:00
    5680838251168988404     alan.comnes@mail.com  2923605896229594830      test6@mail.com 06/01/2000 05:00:00
    2351312285811012730       dab@sprintmail.com 17171333544033270402      test7@mail.com 07/01/2000 06:00:00
    328278708432069254      ana.correa@mail.com 33840664403556851587      test8@mail.com 08/01/2000 07:00:00
    1127901879852039037   andrew.fastow@mail.com  1973548136161209824      test9@mail.com 09/01/2000 08:00:00
    7349515121496417787 elena.kapralova@mail.com  5680838251168988404     test10@mail.com 10/01/2000 09:00:00
    27488842661591306920      bob.shults@mail.com   328278708432069254     test11@mail.com 11/01/2000 10:00:00
    38124472891255273775   carolyn.green@mail.com  1127901879852039037     test12@mail.com 12/01/2000 11:00:00
    29070047663451376630      chris.long@mail.com 27488842661591306920     test13@mail.com 13/01/2000 12:00:00
    8261398433828474582 christi.nicolay@mail.com 38124472891255273775     test14@mail.com 14/01/2000 13:00:00
    18727221862165338513  alan.aronowitz@mail.com 29070047663451376630     test15@mail.com 15/01/2000 14:00:00
    5680838251168988404     alan.comnes@mail.com  8261398433828474582     test16@mail.com 16/01/2000 15:00:00
    2351312285811012730       dab@sprintmail.com  2351312285811012730     test17@mail.com 17/01/2000 16:00:00
    328278708432069254      ana.correa@mail.com  7349515121496417787     test18@mail.com 18/01/2000 17:00:00
    1127901879852039037   andrew.fastow@mail.com 41762759923562968495     test19@mail.com 19/01/2000 18:00:00
    7349515121496417787 elena.kapralova@mail.com 24894056753582090007     test20@mail.com 20/01/2000 19:00:00
    27488842661591306920      bob.shults@mail.com 18727221862165338513 ana.correa@mail.com 01/01/2000 00:00:00
    27488842661591306920      bob.shults@mail.com 18727221862165338513 ana.correa@mail.com 02/01/2000 00:00:00
```

Attempt at levels/factor method:

Getting an error:

```
log <- union(levels(log[,3]), levels(log[,4]))
>Error in emails[, 3] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Don't know much about R, but from what you mention, you are looking for a unique identifier for the combination of the From and To email addresses. You can try creating a hash for the concatenation of them. R seems to have some hashing functions, so you can try that out.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, surely there is an simpler solution than implementing a checksum or hashmap though?!

Comment: you can use any algorithm (md5,sha,crc,..) as long as you get a unique identifier for each input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MD5 to generate globally unique identifiers since it has a very low probability of collisions, but since its output is 128-bit you need a few numbers to represent it (four integers in 32-bit R, two integers in 64-bit R). This should be easy to deal with using short numeric vectors, though.

Here is how you can generate such a vector of four integers for an email address (or any other string for that matter):

```
library(digest)
email <- 'test1@gmail'
as.numeric(paste('0x', substr(rep(hmac('secret56f8a7', email, algo='md5'), 4), c(1, 9, 17, 25), c(8, 16, 24, 32)), sep=''))
```

You could use `algo='crc32'` and obtain just one integer, but this isn't recommended since collisions are far more likely with CRC.

Comment: thanks for your input - Unfortunately this solution didn't seem to work for me. Check out the output above, I (very) possibly could be making a few slips. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a unique id for every email in your logs. One way would be to calculate the crc checksum of every email and use that as a identifier, but it will be very long number. Or you could implement a hashmap in R and make the email the key of the hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want, and it's efficient, and you can do it using only base packages...

Procedure:

1.Convert both columns to factors

2.Union the factor levels, in exactly the same way, so that each email has a unique ID in the factor levels.

3.Change the entries in each column to the number corresponding to their factor level.  As a result, we can identify the times when "test1@gmail.com" sent and received emails by simply looking up "1" in both columns.

```
log1$From <- as.factor(log1$From) 
log1$To <- as.factor(log1$To) 
emails <- union(levels(log1$From), levels(log1$To))
levels(log1$From) <- emails
levels(log1$To) <- emails
log1$From <- as.numeric(log1$From) 
log1$To <- as.numeric(log1$To)
```

It will probably be a good idea to keep a record of the original email addresses, as I have done here.  Then if you were interested in, say, which emails test1@gmail.com sent:

```
log1[log1$From == which(emails == "test1@gmail.com"), ]
```

should do the trick!  You can write a procedure to make that look much cleaner as well...

Comment: ,thanks for your input - Unfortunately I'm getting an error with this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't ensure that upon reading a different log the same email address will receive the same numeric ID as is required by the OP.